# error TS2769: No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error

Tags: json, typescript, redis, web-config

I use Redis and Connfig  with this code

```
// 1. Create Session
  redisClient.set(`${user.id}`, JSON.stringify(user), {
    EX: config.get<any>('redisCacheExpiresIn') * 60,
  });
```

and give error from typescript like that

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ EX: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<"OK">'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'EX' does not exist in type 'Callback<"OK">'.

29     EX: config.get<any>('redisCacheExpiresIn') * 60,

 node_modules/ioredis/built/utils/RedisCommander.d.ts:3557:5
3557     set(key: RedisKey, value: string | Buffer | number, callback?: Callback<"OK">): Result<"OK", Context>;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The last overload is declared here.
```

and redis Commander line code

```
    set(key: RedisKey, value: string | Buffer | number, callback?: Callback<"OK">): Result<"OK", Context>;
```

how can i fix that problem

tnx for help

Answer (score 0):

In ioredis (at least version 5.3.2 which is the latest currently), if you want to specify an expiration time, you need to add the "EX" and the value as separated arguments in the set call.

Hence, for solving your problem, you can call like this:

```
redisClient.set(`${user.id}`, JSON.stringify(user), "EX", config.get<any>('redisCacheExpiresIn') * 60);
```

which matches to this overload:

```
set(key: RedisKey, value: string | Buffer | number, secondsToken: "EX", seconds: number | string, callback?: Callback<"OK">): Result<"OK", Context>;
```